# how to write an If statement that has some disposable objects in it

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have following piece of C# code

```
  iSomeObject.MyPoint(SomeConstants.cpU, 2,
                          myInterface.MySystem.MyCustomType == OtherConstants.cpProjected ? Constants.cpU : Constants.cpT,
                          1, ref t1, ref t2, ref t3);
```

When I ran my proprietary analysis tool it says that myInterface.MySystem is causing a resource leak.

```
 class MyClass:MyInterface,IDisposable
 {}
  MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
```

And I'm explicitly disposing off instance myInstance by casting it back to IDisposable and calling Dipose() method on it.

Now MySystem properties' get method is invoked on myInterface which(MySystem) is of type IExampleInterface which is further implemented like the following code:

```
 class ExampleClass:IExampleClass,IDisposable
 {}
```

I'm not sure whether calling a Dipose() method on myInterface will also dispose off resource created by MySystem or do I need to explicitly call Dispose() method on it as well. But all is happening inside IF statement condition and I'm not sure how to handle this situation and make my code dispose off all disposable objects in other words I'm not sure about the C# syntax in this case and how to deal with dispoal concept in such a scenario.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you implement IDisposable on your interface?

Comment: Could you add `IDisposable` to `MyInterface`?  Then you wouldn't need any casting, and static analysis could follow the whole thing.

Comment: @recursive on other hand deriving from `IDisposable` add very strong requirement to class that implements of the interface - may not be suitable for many cases.

Comment: It's a legacy code and I'm not supposed to make any changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

If MySystem is an IDisposable object then your class should dispose of that object in it's implementation of Dispose.

Otherwise fix your static analysis tool.

Comment: MySystem is of type IExampleInterface which is implemented by ExampleClass along with IDisposable. So IExampleInterface doesn't inherit IDisposable directly on it rather is implemented by ExampleClass which also implements IExampleInterface as mentioned earlier in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should put the disposal at the layer of code that's aware that you have a `MyClass`.

```
using(var iSomeObject = new MyClass(...)) {
    // do something 
    iSomeObject.MyPoint(SomeConstants.cpU, 2,
                      myInterface.MySystem.MyCustomType == OtherConstants.cpProjected ? Constants.cpU : Constants.cpT,
                      1, ref t1, ref t2, ref t3);
}
```

Comment: Yeah actually I didn't show the entire code but I'm already doing this by putting a using statement around iAnotherObject and then rest of the code inside the curly braces.However I need to run static analysis to see whether my tool complaints about it anymore or not. How iAnotherObject is related to iSomeObject is as follows: ISomeobject iSomeObject = (ISomeObject)iAnotherObject; Not sure that after putting iAnother in a using statement and then rest of the code inside it would dispose off myInterface.MySystem or not.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for me to offer any better guesses, but I can say this.  In general, static analysis works better when you avoid casts.  See if you can find a way to eliminate the cast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by the if statement. If you use disposable instances in a method / property / constructor (whatever) and they are not scoped as instance members to the class they should be disposed of immediately after use.

If you have members in the class that implement IDisposable then your class should also implement IDisposable and the Dispose should be called as soon as an instance of your class is no longer needed (just like anything else that implements IDisposable).

Also always use a try/finally or using block when interacting with instances that implement IDisposable.

Finally see [this write up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx)  from Microsoft for complete details and best practices for using IDisposable.

```
public interface IExampleInterface { void DoSomething();}
public class ExampleClass : IExampleInterface, IDisposable {

   private bool _switch = true;

   public void DoSomething() {
       // lets use something disposable
       if(_switch) { // is this what you mean by in an if statement??
          var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
          try {
              // do something with stream
          } finally {
              stream.Dispose(); // call dispose!
          }
       }
   }
   private System.IO.FileStream fs; // class level field
   public void Dispose(){
      // dispose of class fields here that implement IDisposable
      if(fs != null)
         fs.Dispose();
      fs = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to manipulate any existing implementation of IDisposable since it's a legacy code.

Comment: @user2913184 From your description it sounds like you are the one adding the IDisposable interface to this 'legacy' code. If you are adding the interface to the class then you should also be adding an implementation of that interface. If this is not right then please provide a more clear example.